# Python: removing only the first instance of a tag from a text file?

Tags: python, text, insert

I've got a file that at the moment reads along these lines:

```
Text
Text
</tag> <tag> Line
Text
Text
</tag> <tag> Line
Text
</tag>
etc.
```

I'd like to remove only the first instance of the /tag (as obviously this is wrong and shouldn't be there).

So far I've tried something along the lines of:

```
with open(document.txt, r+) as doc:
   for line in doc:
      line = line.replace("</tag>", " ")
   doc.write(line)
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything to the file.

I've also tried a different method that involves effectively not inserting the first /tag before I insert the rest (as I'm the one inserting /tag tag into the document), by:

```
#insert first tag
with open('document.txt', 'r+') as doc:
   for line in doc:
      with open('document.txt', 'r') as doc:
         lines = doc.readlines()

      if line.__contains__("Line"):
         lines.insert(3, "<tag>")

      with open(document.txt', 'w') as doc:
         contents = doc.writelines(lines)

#insert other sets of tags
with open('document.txt', 'r+') as doc:
    for line in doc:
        with open('document.txt', 'r') as doc:
                lines = doc.readlines()
        
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):      
            if line.__contains__("Line") and not line.__contains__("<tag>"):
                lines.insert(index, "</tag> <tag>")
                break
    
        with open('document.txt', 'w') as doc:
            contents = doc.writelines(lines)
```

This again however seems to just give me the same result as before - with all of the tags, including the first /tag.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this? Apologies if the above is shoddy coding and there's a simple fix.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str.replace(old, new [, count])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) takes an optional argument `count`, which replaces only the first count occurrences:

```
filename = "file.txt"
data = open(filename).read()
data = data.replace("</tag>", " ", 1)
with open(filename, "w") as doc:
    doc.write(data)
print(open(filename).read())
```

Out:

```
Text
Text
  <tag> Line
Text
Text
</tag> <tag> Line
Text
</tag>
etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use the fileinput module for this. From the Python Website https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html

```py
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(encoding="utf-8"):
    process(line)
```

You can use this to process line by line in place. By using the replace function you can modify each of your lines. If there are multiple tags in each line and you always want to only remove the first one, replace also has a count argument.

```py
import fileinput


def main():
    filename = "input.txt"
    for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
        print(line.replace("<tag/>", ""), end="")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I hope this helps!